# Best strategy to update symfony project skeleton

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a customized symfony-project and a custom vendor. In the `composer.json` of the project the type is set to "project". To update my vendor I use `composer update`. So far, so good.

But how do I update my project itself? It's installed by composer's `create-project`, but I know that such as `update-project` does not exist for composer. What is the best strategy to keep my "skeleton" up-to-date? Using git would require to `init git` repository and checkout the right branch/tag. So that's not my favourite solution for end-users and release-management. What other methodologies can be used to tackle this scenario?

Comment: What do you mean by skeleton?

Comment: I mean the Project itself... Following folder-structure:
  
- [app]  
- [bin]  
- [vendor]  
- [web]  
- composer.json  
- etc...  

with composer update i can only update packages within the vendor folder, but how about the rest? app-folder (which contains config-files etc.). with skeleton i mean all other stuff outside vendor folder

Comment: Minor versions are not supposed to modify the skeleton, only Symfony3 will introduce some modifications.

Comment: Still not really clear what you are asking.  On the development side you would use git push to update your repository.  To deploy your end user would use git clone followed by composer install.  To update the end user would use git pull followed by composer update.  Of course there are many other delivery approaches which would hide the git/composer commands from the end user.  But it seems like you are asking for something else?

Comment: No, that is exactly what i mean. I want the update to be as easy as possible for enduser... `Of course there are many other delivery approaches which would hide the git/composer commands from the end user.` Can you tell me more about that? What kind of delivery approaches do you mean?

Comment: (maybe my poor english is a problem too). The Situation: I've downloaded symfony and put it in my git repo (A). I've created a vendor in a second repo (B) and connect it via composer.json. So far so good. Enduser can run `composer create-project xxxx`to install the app. he can call `composer update` to update my vendor. But now, i've modified a file outside the vendor-folder in Repo (A). The Enduser can't get theses modifications by running `composer update`. But how he can get it as easy as possible? (without `git fetch`, `git checkout tag/x.x.x` etc...  to be manually executed).

Comment: the easiest solution sure is git

Comment: Here is a list of tools that might help: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/deployment/tools.html.  And no, the end user would never use composer create-project to install an app.  create-project is only used by developers as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

There is no better alternative, as the skeleton is completely free. You can use Symfony by just adding a `symfony/symfony` dependency and creating your own directory structure.

This means that while most projects start with the skeleton, projects can tweak it to fit their needs. Also, some bundles included by the skeleton may be removed from the project or a project uses different settings than the skeleton.

Each time a new skeleton version is released, you can check the diff (e.g. https://github.com/symfony/symfony-standard/compare/v2.7.2...v2.7.3 ) and check the changes and apply the changes to your project whenever they're needed in your project.

Comment: Ok, many thanks. That answering my question... So i have to find another way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm testing another approach at the moment. I've created a bash-script which is included in the composer.json at the post-install- and post-update-part. I know that has to be exists, but with this, the enduser only have to do a `composer update`

**composer.json**

```
[...]
    "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "chmod +x init_update_app && ./init_update_app"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
      "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::removeSymfonyStandardFiles",
      "chmod +x update_app && ./update_app"
    ]
  },
[...]
```

**Post-Install:**

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! git ls-remote origin > /dev/null; then
    git init
    git remote add origin https://github.com/xxx/xxx.git
fi
git fetch --tags
latestTag=$(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
git checkout $latestTag
```

**Post-Update:**

```
#!/bin/bash

git fetch --tags
latestTag=$(git describe --tags `git rev-list --tags --max-count=1`)
git checkout $latestTag
```

Any disadvantages with this approach? I know that git have to be installed but that is not the problem. The scripts could be improved by checking the existing tag to prevent checking out the same tag again or to check if git is installed...